# UIImageView half moon slice

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to create an app with groups you can switch between. My idea was to pick the first 3 photo's of the members in the group, and lay the images over each other. Adding three images over each other is not really difficult, the difficult part for me is to make the other two images show up like a "half moon" beneath the other images. See the attached image for an example.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a combination of `cornerRadius` and border do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really a half moon. It's more like a crescent moon or lunate shape.

The principle is not a difficult one. Practice as follows:

1. Start with an image, roughly a square.
2. Make an image context the same size as the image.
3. Fill a circle the size of the image, roughly offset about a third of its width to the left.
4. Fill *another* circle the size of the image, roughly offset about *two* thirds of its width to the left, using Clear blend mode.
5. Extract the resulting image from the image context.

You now have the desired lunate shape:

[image]

Now use that lunate shape as a mask or clipping area for the original image:

[image]

Comment: Thans for the clear answer and the push in the right direction! I've been playing with UIBezierPath but unfortunately aren't experienced enough to create the shape you mentioned. Do you have a example on how to implement this in Objective-C?

Comment: If you don't understand how to do what I said, read the Drawing chapter of my book... http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html